# Count instances of string in a very large array and add the value to a hash value

Tags: javascript

I have a very large array of words in an array, and I want to count all of them and add the count as a value to each string.

So I for example:

```
words = ["a", "hello", "hello", "b", "went", "a"]
```

I want to convert this into:

```
words = [{"a" => 2}, {"b" => 1}, {"hello" => 2}, {"went" => 1}]
```

I have seen ways to simply count one word in a string and return its occurrences, but how might I do this at a large scale, while creating an array of hashes with the number of occurrences?

I can remove duplicate values after, I am more interested in the process of counting the values and adding the count as values in a hash.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please keep in mind that SO is not a code writing service. So please provide the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: My bad, will put some code in here shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first turn you can create an object with the array value and number of occurrence.Then loop through it to create an array of objects

```js
var words = ["a", "hello", "hello", "b", "went", "a"];
var rObj = {};
var finalArray = [];
words.map(function(currentValue, index) {
  if (rObj.hasOwnProperty(currentValue)) {
    rObj[currentValue] = rObj[currentValue] + 1;
  } else {
    rObj[currentValue] = 1
  }

});
for (var keys in rObj) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[keys] = rObj[keys];
  finalArray.push(obj)
};
console.log(finalArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first use `reduce()` to count elements and return object and then `map()` to return array of object values.

```js
var words = ["a", "hello", "hello", "b", "went", "a"]
var count = words.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if(!r[e]) r[e] = {[e]: 1}
  else r[e][e] += 1
  return r;
}, {})

var result = Object.keys(count).map(e => count[e])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: `reduce` is a good choice. Though depending on how "huge" the array is, you might want to implement this using a `for` loop.

Comment: Why don't you put `(r[e] ? r[e] += 1 : r[e] = 1); return r;` inside `words.reduce`? It would save the `map` call. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: @gus27 Op wants array of objects as result.

Answer (score 1):

For a really huge array, I suggest to use either a `while` of a `for` loop and a plain check if the key with the word exist. If not assign zero to it. Later increment the property of the count object.

At last convert the object into an array with the wanted structure.

```js
var words = ["a", "hello", "hello", "b", "went", "a"],
    w,
    i = words.length,  
    count = Object.create(null),
    result;
    
while (i--) {
    w = words[i];
    if (!count[w]) {
        count[w] = 0;
    }
    count[w]++;
}

result = Object.keys(count).map(function (k) {
    var temp = {};
    temp[k] = count[k];
    return temp;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: is there a way around using the map that will optimize for speed like an assignment? Or am I wrong about that assumption?

Comment: @Arrow, at least, you need to try both methods first, but i think an object is faster, because it has only strings as key, whereas `Map` can have any type of key.

Answer (score 0):

Don't count repeaters by hashing. Use a while loop for smaller overhead. Assignments over calculation. You will get an answer on orders of magnitude 5 times faster. One million words randomly generated from 12 words in a 1/5th of the time.

```js
var wordsArray = ['apple', 'beer', 'cake', 'potato', 'orange', 'monitor', 'program', 'application', 'keyboard', 'javascript', 'gaming', 'network'],
  words = [];
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  words.push(wordsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsArray.length)]);
}

function getCount(words) {
  var w,
    i = words.length,
    hash = {};
  while (i--) {
    w = words[i];
    if (!hash[w]) {
      hash[w] = 0;
    }
    hash[w]++;
  }
  return hash
}

console.time('Obj-time');
var counts = getCount(words);
array = [];
for (let i in counts) {
  var l = i.length,
    val = counts[i];
  array.push({
    [i]: val * l
  })
}

console.log(array);
console.timeEnd('Obj-time');
```